# purrr::accumulate() on two cumulated variables not just 1

Tags: r, purrr

I have a model that as a predictor has the previous prediction. e.g. `target ~ lag(target prediction)`

Using purrr::accumulate I'm able to write a custom function to predict. Example of some silly data and a silly model that illustrates:

```
 ### A model that uses a lag prediction as a predictor using purrr::accumulate() ###
my_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(cumprice = cumsum(price)) %>% # cumulative within groups
  mutate(lag_cumprice = lag(cumprice)) %>% 
  mutate(InitialValue = min(cumprice)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(lag_cumprice)) %>% 
  select(cut, cumprice, lag_cumprice, x, InitialValue)

silly_model <- glm(formula = cumprice ~ x + lag_cumprice, family = 'poisson', data = my_diamonds)
```

This model uses the previous prediction as input to the next prediction. I'm able to write a custom function to mutate a prediction:

```
# when predicting won't have lag_cumprice, instead the result of the previous pediction should be an input to the model:
accPrice <- function(mod, acc, cur) {
  
  db=cur_data_all() # grouped data segment
  x = db$x[cur] # cur is the current row in the data, use it to get 'this' iterations value of x
  
  total_exponent <- mod$coefficients['(Intercept)'] + 
    (mod$coefficients['x'] * x) +
    (mod$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * acc) # acc is the accumulated prediction for cumprice
}

# now predict
my_diamonds <- my_diamonds %>% 
  mutate(predicted = accumulate(.x = row_number()[-1], .init = InitialValue %>% unique, .f = accPrice, mod = silly_model))
```

So far so good. In this example I used the previous prediction `acc` as an input.

But, I created a variation model that now uses two lagged variables as predictors:

```
### now a model with lag on two variables not just one ###
my_diamonds2 <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut) %>% 
  mutate(cumprice = cumsum(price)) %>% # cumulative within groups
  mutate(lag_cumprice = lag(cumprice)) %>% 
  mutate(InitialValue = min(cumprice)) %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(cumrn = cumsum(rn)) %>% 
  mutate(lag_cumrn = lag(cumrn)) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(lag_cumprice)) %>% 
  select(cut, cumprice, lag_cumprice, lag_cumrn, x, InitialValue)

silly_model2 <- glm(formula = cumprice ~ x + lag_cumprice + lag_cumrn, family = 'poisson', data = my_diamonds2)

### Stuck after here ###
```

How can I modify the function accPrice() above to accumulate 2 variables, both lag_cumprice and lag_cumrn as opposed to just lag_cumprice as before?

Comment: there is `accumulate2`

Comment: @akrun right, I got existed when I saw that but maybe I misunderstood the documentation... as far as I could tell accumulate2() doesn't accumulate on 2 vars, instead it just allows you to pass an additional var to the func. Unless I misread it? I find this particular r problem more challenging than others I've wrestled with in the past

Comment: A `for`loop option would be more direct

Comment: Bsaed on the post, you are not using `lag_cumprice' or `lag_cumrn` in the function?

Comment: in the second data, why you are removing the `cumrn`

Comment: I'm using `lag_cumprice` in the fist example within the accPrice() func (`(mod$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * acc)`). What I want is to be able to write a funt in a similar manner that uses both `lag_cumprice` AND `lag_cumrn` in the same function. I.e. something like `...  (mod$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * acc) +  (mod$coefficients['lag_cumrn'] * acc2)`

Comment: you can add a new parameter into the function `accPrice2 <- function(mod, acc, acc2, cur)`

Comment: "in the second data, why you are removing the cumrn" Because when it comes to predicting, I wont have this. I need to accumulate it up. I used it for 'training' but when predicting cumrn won't be known, instead I'll have to predict it cumulativley like I do with lag_cumprice

Comment: "you can add a new parameter into the function accPrice2 <- function(mod, acc, acc2, cur)" Oh! That sounds good. Let me try that now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could add an argument to the function.  Then, extract the corresponding coefficient from the model and multiply by it

```
accPrice2 <- function(mod, acc, acc2, cur) {
   
   db=cur_data_all() # grouped data segment
   x = db$x[cur] # cur is the current row in the data, use it to get 'this' iterations value of x
   
   total_exponent <- mod$coefficients['(Intercept)'] + 
     (mod$coefficients['x'] * x) +
     (mod$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * acc)  + 
    (mod$coefficients['lag_cumrn'] * acc2)
 }

my_diamonds2 %>% 
   mutate(predicted = accumulate(.x = row_number()[-1], 
      .init = InitialValue %>%
              unique, .f = accPrice2, mod = silly_model))
```

Comment: Amazing! It does run! Thank you very much. One loose end with it, When calling it, on the last line I use initial value with `.init`. When it runs presumably it's using this same initial value for both acc and acc2? Any idea how to say 'use .init for lag_cumprice initial value and e.g. .init2 for the lag_cumrn initial value'

Comment: @DougFir I was also thinking about your structure.  The `InitialValue'` is created from the `min` of 'cumprice',  what will the corresponding for cumrn

Comment: For this example, it would just be the same but for cumrn, so when I created the second example dataset I should have added something like `mutate(InitialValueRN = min(cumrn)) %>% `

Comment: @DougFir wouldn't the `min(cumrn)` always 1

Comment: Ah! I guess in this example yes. But with my real data it will not be. I'll need to somehow pass a value to accumulate that tells it the initial value of the second var to be accumulated. I'm thinking of some if() logic within the function that uses `cur` e.g. `if(cur==1) acc2 = min(myvar) else acc2`. Am I thinking about this right?

Comment: @DougFir yes, that sounds good.  But, then `acc2` will be just the row_number() that you are looping

Comment: @DougFir I would say with more than one initialization parameters, it is better to use for loop as that will be more clear instead of trying to do in accumulate

Comment: @DougFir i.e. Do a group split `lst1 <- my_diamonds2 %>%
    group_split()`, Then loop over the list with `map/lapply`, create a function with `for` loop with multiple initializations and apply that function

Comment: What I meant was  I would do e.g. `if(cur==1) acc2 = db$myvar[curr] else acc2`